# How to deploy a serverless project bigger than one CloudFormation stack while lambda functions are having aliases

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy a serverless yaml file that does not fit into a single CloudFormation stack. Searching online, it seems there are plugins for that. So far, I've tested `serverless-plugin-split-stacks`. It works but...

I managed to deploy my project which includes more than 200 CloudFormation resources (I couldn't do this without the aforementioned plugin). It's just that, I need to use the `serverless-aws-alias` plugin as well. Previously, without the `serverless-plugin-split-stacks` plugin, I was deploying my project and the `serverless-aws-alias` plugin was creating the aliases for me without any issues.

But now (after adding `serverless-plugin-split-stacks` plugin), the lambda function are created has with no aliases. I looked into the CloudFormation stack list and I can see the stack for the alias but still not alias is actually created for the lambda.

I was wondering if anyone has actually managed to deploy a serverless function with more than one stack while using the `serverless-aws-alias` plugin!?

**[UPDATE]**

Here's a simple test case:

```
service: serverless-test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  endpointType:                                REGIONAL

plugins:
- serverless-plugin-split-stacks
- serverless-aws-alias

custom:
  splitStacks:
    nestedStackCount: 20
    perFunction: false
    perType: false
    perGroupFunction: true

functions:
  create:
    handler: code.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          integration:                           lambda
          method: get
          cors: true
```

If you deploy this `serverless.yml` file like this:

```
sls deploy --region us-east-1 --stage dev --alais dev
```

The lambda functions created won't have any aliases (as they should). And these are the version of the packages I use:

```
$ sls -v
Framework Core: 1.61.2
Plugin: 3.6.6
SDK: 2.3.0
Components Core: 1.1.2
Components CLI: 1.4.0

$ cat ./package.json 
{
  "name": "serverless-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "code.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless-aws-alias": "^1.8.0",
    "serverless-plugin-split-stacks": "^1.9.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I haven't tested this in a while but back then the only solution I could find was to use Cloud Formation directly. Serverless framework did not support it back then.